# htaccess and index on google

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have to domains: `example.com` and `example.dk`. I am using the last one as my homepage, and I would use the first one as my testserver.

I have a unique name, that nobody in the world has. Therefore if use search on my name on Google, I do not want my name showing up on my testserver, so people are going to the wrong page.

I solved that with making:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from myip
```

which is working fine. But does that also block the site from search engines, so if people are searching on my name, the domain `example.com` is not showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put a robots.txt file in your root directory of your testserver with the following contents:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This will inform the legitimate search engines that you do not want to be indexed, but it will not stop malware bots.  This means when the indexing bots come through, they will not crawl through the website.

You can read about it more [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That would also count if I made 5 subdomains on the server? Fx `a.example.com`, `b.example.com`, `c.example.com` etc, or did I had to put the robots.txt on each root of the subdomain?

Comment: You need to put a robots.txt in the home directory of any website you do not want to be indexed.  You can change the robots.txt to also say you want parts allowed or disallowed, or the whole thing allowed, it is up to you (you can read more in the link I suggested.